# Replace Specified Values With New Values in a DataFrame Column in Scala Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to replace specified values from let's say 'Col1' with New values. 
Let's say I have a list of values to replace

```
from: [1,2,3]
to: ['one','two','three']
```

I know I can use the .withColumn and say `when 1 then "one" otherwise` etc. but when my list of values is long, this is not very convenient. Same with udf. I am assuming there should be some kind of mapValues function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dataframe of new values mapped with old values and do a join.
If `map_df` has the key pairs and `orig_df` is original dataframe then.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

new_df = orig_df.join(map_df, 'old_key', 'left')

new_df = new_df.withColumn('final_col', when(isnull(col('new_key')), col('old_key')).otherwise(col('new_key')))

new_df = new_df.drop('old_key').drop('new_key').withColumnRenamed('final_col', 'old_key')
```

The `new_df` is your dataframe.

Comment: I feel like this becomes slow, no? In R you can do the following:
   `df$”Col2” <- mapvalues(df$Col1,
                                      from=c(1, 2, 3),
                                      to=c(“one”, “two”, “thre"))` 
And I was hoping there is a similar function in Spark

Comment: It depends upon the data size, if it justifies the overhead time. In Spark's playground, R is stopped outside the gate.